# jQuery click handler acting strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I have this line of code in my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#faye').click(function() {
        $('#fayebig').fadeIn(1000);
    })
    $('#faye').click(function() {   
        $('#fayebig').fadeOut(500);

    });
```

What I'm aiming at is when I click #faye, #fayebig should appear (which is does) and when you click again on #faye, #fayebig should disappear.

What my code does though, is when I click on #faye, the #fayebig fades in and then right again fades out, like the script runs the through the whole process without letting me click again to let it fade out.

Hope you catch my drift, it should be fairly easy to deal with this I'm just shooting blanks here with this apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) otherwise two of them will happen at same time

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#faye').click(function() {
        $('#fayebig').fadeToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

While using `fadeToggle` it will toggle between `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

If you want different duration for each fade then use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#faye').click(function() {
        $('#fayebig').fadeToggle(function(){ return $(this).is(':visible') ? 500 : 1000});
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 even you could set different duration for each fade: `$('#fayebig').fadeToggle($(this).is(':visible') ? 500 : 1000);`

Comment: @A.Wolff : that's really nice sir

Comment: I think it is not correct because `this` will refers to #faye element

Comment: Hey Pranav, that's wonderful, even fewer lines of code and really simple! Thanks for your input and also to you A.Wolff !

Comment: I'd try: `.fadeToggle(function(){ return $(this).is(':visible') ? 500 : 1000})`

Comment: then `$('#fayebig').fadeToggle($('#fayebig').is(':visible') ? 500 : 1000);`

Comment: @A.Wolff : yeah ! that's the right way , using callback function it's more simple

Comment: @A.Wolff : sir,can I include it to my answer??

Comment: @PranavCBalan of course you can, this was purpose of comment ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46945/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-a-wolff)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Pranav answer, you should use "stop(true, true)" function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#faye').click(function() {
        $('#fayebig').stop(true,true).fadeToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 , Yes you are correct ,otherwise there will be a delay. to complete previous animation